# Selenium in Python, Unable to Click 'button': Tag not found

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, iframe

*TL,DR:*

For whatever reason, my selenium python script can't seem to "click" on the buttons I need.

*Context:*

Hello. My task is one many are probably familiar with: I'd like to automate the process of opening a website, logging in, and clicking on a few drop-down menu links within the website, which will ultimately lead me to a page where I can download a spreadsheet. I'm able to open the web page and log in. To proceed, I have to:

1. Click on the drop down menu header, and
2. in the drop down menu, click on the appropriate option.

Here's a snapshot of the pertinent HTML code from the website:

```
<td class="x-toolbar-cell" id="ext-gen45">
    <table id="ext-comp-1045" class="x-btn x-btn-noicon" style="width: auto;" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
            <tr>
                <td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                <td class="x-btn-mc">
                    <em class="x-btn-arrow" unselectable="on">
    <button type="button" id="ext-gen46" class=" x-btn-text">Reports</button>
</em>
                </td>
                <td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

The item I need to "click" has a `button` tag, specifically:

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen46" class=" x-btn-text">Reports</button>
```

To select it with selenium, I've tried the following:

```
reports_click_element = browser.find_element_by_id('ext-gen46').click()
```

and when that failed,

```
reports_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Reports')]").click()
```

That one actually executed without an ExceptionMessage error, but I found out it was selecting other elements in the page that had "Reports" text, as opposed to the particular button I need.

When I've tried to zero in on the button I need clicked, the interpreter returned an error message indicating that the html attributes could not be found.

How can I proceed from here? (Should I be focusing on the `unselectable="on"` tag in the element right above the button I need clicked?)

Please let me know if I can add anything to the question. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I *have* switched into an iframe that I believe the menu is a part of- but I *still* cannot select the button. So far, here is my Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

browser.get("https://app.website.com")

login_entry(username, password) # this works fine; it's just a user-created function to login. Ignore.

time.sleep(10) # wait for website's markup to load
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
time.sleep(10)

# This is the point where I'm trying to click on the "Reports" button
reports_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Reports')]") #this refers to other elements
reports_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Reports')][1]") #no luck here either
```

Comment: Are these elements inside of an iframe? If so, you will need to switch to the iframe context and then grab the elements you are looking for. You generally want to use the right-click and Inspect menu to determine the HTML and locators. FYI... `*_by_link_text()` only applies to A tags so it won't find a button that contains that text.

Comment: Thanks for responding @JeffC. I added an "update" section above to my question.

Comment: So all you need to do is to switch into the IFRAME before grabbing the desired element.

Comment: Are you trying this on salesforce?

Comment: @daOnlyBG, `browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))` should match first `iframe` element in `HTML` tree. You need to switch to exact frame. Show `HTML` for target `iframe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

Print the `DOM` source of the iframe and check if the `html` is what you expected:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

browser.get("https://app.website.com")

login_entry(username, password) # this works fine; it's just a user-created function to login. Ignore.

time.sleep(10) # wait for website's markup to load
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
time.sleep(10)

print browser.page_source
```

It could be, for example, that you switched to the wrong `iframe`, in case there is more than one in the page.

If the `html` is correct, then you could try to use the `id` of the button instead of trying to get it by text:

```
reports_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ext-gen46']")
```

If that still doesn't work, you can try to click the button with javascript:

```
browser.execute_script("""
    (function() {
        document.getElementById("ext-gen46").click();
    })()
""")
```

You can even include jQuery by saving jQuery in a local file, then storing the contents to a variable, and running, like:

```
with open(JQUERY_PATH) as f:
    jquery = f.read()

browser.execute_script(jquery)
```

Then you could use it to click the button with:

```
driver.execute_script("""
    (function() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#ext-gen46').click();
        }, jQuery)
    })()
""")
```

Comment: Your answer helped. It turns out that the element wasn't even in an `iframe` to begin with! Others suggested I switch into an iframe. Had I just "waited" 10 seconds initially before switching into the iframe, there would have been no issue. It was very, very close b/w you and Naveen; you both suggested that I may be in the wrong iframe, or that the element I'm looking for isn't in an iframe altogether. I chose your answer because you included the `browser.page_source` line, which I didn't know I could use. It really helped me figure out what had downloaded at any given time. A BIG thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of cases which came to mind.

More than one element exists but not all are visible

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Reports')]")
for element in elements:

    if element.is_displayed():
        print "element is visible"
        element.click()
    else:
        print("element is not visible")
        print(element)
```

The element exists, it would be visible but is out of screen.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Reports')]")
for element in elements:  
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
    try:
        element.click()
    except:
        print("couldn't click on {}".format(element))
```

---

Can you also try to record your clicks and keyboard entries with 
[Selenium IDE for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/)? Then save it as a python script and post it as a comment here?

Comment: Should be `find_elements_by_xpath` instead. Please correct it. Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: Thanks for catching this one! I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The "page source" is only what comes with the document request. It will not show any DOM elements created via javascript after the page loads. It does sound like your elements are within some sort of iframe. In the browser console, try this and see if it returns any elements:

`document.querySelectorAll('iframe')`

EDIT for your update:

Once again, the page source is only what is available at document load. Everything that comes afterward that is loaded dynamically can only be seen by using the browser inspector or by getting parts of the document w/ javascript. The link being basically the same html is probably because it is a link that acts with javascript and isn't meant to lead to an actual html document page. You probably need to do in your code is:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe'))
reports_element = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Reports')
reports_element.click()
```

Comment: Once again, thanks for responding. Fortunately I was able to select the `iframe` using `browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))`, but unfortunately, the program isn't able to pick up the tag with the text "Reports." It just returns this error: 
`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate ele
ment: Reports`

Comment: Are you sure the 'Reports' element is a link `<a>`? Without seeing any html this is going to be hard to help any further

Comment: I will provide more detailed HTML code above, but for now, it doesn't seem that I can click on this thing. The "Reports" element is actually a button. I'm considering attaching a bounty on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following things to try:

1. **Switch to the correct frame.**
   There may be a chance of `no frame` or `one frame` or `more than one nested frames`, where your element can be as a child of another. Therefore, you must switch to the `right frame` before you find the element. My detailed answer is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759300/2575259)
2. **Use a more restricted XPATH.** For example:

`report_element =browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td/em/button[text()='Reports']")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar with Siebel OneView, which puts most of its control buttons and menus inside Java screen elements. These elements prevent me from finding the HTML objects to activate with Selenium, so I have fallen back to using `pyautogui`:

```
import pyautogui
import time
#look for and click the Activites menu
try:
    x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('acts_button.png')
    try:
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
    except PermissionError:
        #allow load - note this is AFTER the click permission error
        time.sleep(7)
        pass
except TypeError:
    <code to deal with NOT finding the button>
```

This looks for a copy of a previously taken screenshot, stored in the same file location as the python script. In this section the image is called `acts_button.png`.

[Quick note: There are two `try: except:` statements in here. The inner one deals with any problems clicking the button as Windows will often throw out permission errors. The outer one is more important and tells your script what to do if it can't find the button. In my code, I try clicking on a preset x,y location with `pyautogui.click(958, 169)`; if that fails, I ask the user for input (Failures detected by the next screen not loading).

The screenshots themselves are created by using commands like this

```
 acts_button = pyautogui.screenshot('acts_button.png', region=(928,162,63,15))
```

Where the `region` is a tuple of the following parts of your target button, measured as pixels

- left hand edge
- top edge
- width
- height

Now all you need is a way to find the (x,y) values for when you take the screenshot. Fortunately I have code for that too:

```
#! python3
import pyautogui, sys, time
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

This will pop up a small window with the (x,y) coordinates of the mouse, updating once per second.

The routine to set up a new click event is therefore

1. Open the site you want to navigate
2. Use the mouse locator script to find the settings for the screenshot tuple
3. Use `pyautogui.screenshot` to save an image of the button
4. Use the main script to look for and click that image

After a couple of goes you should be able to set up a new click event in less than a minute. You can either use this method where you *know* Selenium will fail, or as a way of catching and managing exceptions when Selenium *might* fail.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether there is only one `iframe` on current page. You can use

```
len(browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

If output is greater than `1` and you use `browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))`, it means that you're trying to switch to first `iframe` found by `webdriver`, but you actually might need to switch to another `iframe`

**Good** solution is to find required `iframe` in button's ancestors with `F12` or right-click on button + `inspect element` and use specific attributes of `iframe` in `XPath` that will match exact `iframe`, e.g.

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="iframe_class_name"]'))
```

**Bad** solution is to define index of required `iframe` by exhaustive search like:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0])
reports_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Reports'][contains(@id, 'ext-gen')]")
reports_element.click()
...
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[1])
reports_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Reports'][contains(@id, 'ext-gen')]")
reports_element.click()
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use python [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) (with session) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) modules to do this kind of job  (user interact on a website) ?