# seleniumBasic FindElementByXPath inner text

Tags: html, excel, selenium, vba

I have a td tag

```
<td>abcdefg</td>
```

How to reference it by xpath in seleniumBasic?
I have tried:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[@text='abcdefg']")
driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[text()='abcdefg']")
driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[@innertext='abcdefg']")
driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text()='abc')]")
```

all get no-such-element-error

Comment: can you please add more relevant HTML code, may be 4-5 lines above the td tag, required.

Comment: <table>
        <tbody><tr><td>abcdefg</td></tr>
        </tbody></table>

Comment: Are you the table tag is not part of any iframe tag (as a child to iframe tag in the hierarchy from html tag)?

Comment: I don't think the parent tag really matters, because the only reference will be the text "abcdefg" between open tag "<td>" and close tag "</td>"

Comment: I got your point. whatI mentioned is whole different topic altogether. If your element is inside a iframe tag(s), then you need to switch to the frame and then find the element. that's how it works.

Comment: refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758138/in-selenium-web-driver-how-to-choose-the-correct-iframe/40759300#40759300

Comment: thank you very much. I have get it work by :     driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[text()=""abcdefg""]")

Answer (score 2):

ok, this worked.

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[text()=""abcdefg""]")
```