# want to find link/text and Click on it

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using fake mail generator tool to send a mail and click on a link in the mail.. 
[enter link description here](http://www.fakemailgenerator.com/inbox/dayrep.com/ciwqv/)

```
<iframe id="emailFrame" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="360px" src="http://www.fakemailgenerator.com/email/dayrep.com/testlk/message-108204614/" scrolling="no" onload="autoResize('emailFrame')">
 <html>
  <head>
   <body>
    <div>
     <p>Good day - </p>
     <p>You have been assigned an Action from the motion A Name iwhirxpppk: s.    
     </p>
     <p>Kindly follow - up on the Touchpoint Action listed below.
     </p>
     <ul>
     Please click the below link to complete your Action.
     <p>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://cfn- svr001.cloudapp.net:7100/Home/ActionResponse?eid=ygfWFB5a99mtAUQBxjNUDHjpC9AdFz/9&tpid=14iwlvior8ak6FGifOI3MSBNxnNvHiT9">Click here
      </a>
     </p>
     This email has been generated from CFN Insight by Auto man, auto@
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

want to find below part of the code

```
<p>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://cfn-svr001.cloudapp.net:7100/Home/ActionResponse?eid=ygfWFB5a99mtAUQBxjNUDHjpC9AdFz/9&tpid=14iwlvior8ak6FGifOI3MSBNxnNvHiT9">Click here</a>
</p>
```

I tried all possible combinations what ever I know but nothing helped me..
Here are the scripts which I tried

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # for b in
browser.find_element_by_id('emailFrame').find_elements_by_xp‌​ath(".//*"):
    print b # browser.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/p[4]/a") #
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[text()='Click here']") # 
    browser.find_element_by_xpath[".//a[contains(., 'Click here')]"] # 
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[1]//p[4]/a") 
    browser.find_element_by_id('emailFrame').find_elements_by_ta‌​g_name("a"):
```

Comment: want to automate the part
<p>
<a target="_blank" href=".....">Click here</a>

Here are the scripts which I tried but nothing helped me..
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# for b in browser.find_element_by_id('emailFrame').find_elements_by_xpath(".//*"):
    print b
# browser.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/p[4]/a")
# browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[text()='Click here']")
# browser.find_element_by_xpath[".//a[contains(., 'Click here')]"]
# browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[1]//p[4]/a")

browser.find_element_by_id('emailFrame').find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium and iframe in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924146/selenium-and-iframe-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should switch to the frame and then find the element inside it.

try as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("http://www.fakemailgenerator.com/inbox/armyspy.com/morly1985/")
frame = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'emailFrame')
browser.switch_to_frame(frame) # switch to frame by finding the iframe webelement
click_here = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[text()='Click here']") # try different xpaths.
click_here.location_once_scrolled_into_view # As the element needs scroll down
click_here.click()
```

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759300/2575259
2. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames
3. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: Already tried the scripts suggested by Naveen but didn't work. 

Identifies browser.switch_to_frame('emailFrame') but not browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[text()='Click here']")

Comment: updated the code. try it out. how do you know switching to frame worked? what is the exception for finding `Click here` element?

Comment: what is the exception? is it failing when finding the frame? or finding the element? trace is needed to further help you

Comment: Hi Naveen, 
Sorry to say, I updated the code and tried but no luck 
The purpose is, it is basiccaly a link and clicking on the link (Click here) will open another window(/tab)

Here is one page link (http://www.fakemailgenerator.com/inbox/armyspy.com/morly1985/) on I want to find the "Click here" link

Comment: Able to find  frame but not finding the element?

Comment: please add the full code. I am confused about the flow as I don't see browser.get method. add the trace, I'll try find out what is the issue.

Comment: Can you please visit the link - fakemailgenerator.com/inbox/armyspy.com/morly1985,  from this page I want to find the click link

Comment: tried it. the issue seems to be with the scroll. updated the answer. try.