# python selenium webdriver click() not working

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

i am new in Selenium trying to click() in selenium Webdriver but it's not work
i use Firebug and Firepath in Firefox to help me find xpath
i enter this xpath into firepath Firefox, it's highlight all element i want, but not click()
**this is my code**

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@zoneid="A1"]/div').click()
```

**this is page source**

```
<td class="seatSample">
<td id=“C_1" class="seatItem" title=“available” price=“35.0" zoneid="A1" seatname=“C1" style="background-color:#33b093 ;">
<div style=“width:20px;">1</div>
</td>
<td id=“C_2" class="seatItem" title="available" price=“35.0" zoneid="A1" seatname=“C2" style="background-color:#33b093 ;">
<div style=“width:20px;">2</div>
</td>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any exception trace? which element you want to click? you are retrieving more than one webelement using the XPath.

Comment: This answer has helped me against the click():
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54542644/11019692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as follows:

to click the element with text `1`:

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@zoneid="A1"]/div[text()="1"]').click()
```

to click the element with text `2`:

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@zoneid="A1"]/div[text()="2"]').click()
```

Comment: use `find_element_by_xpath` not `find_elements_by_xpath`

Comment: ohh sorry my bad, i try error **Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[@zoneid="A1"]/div[text()="1"]"}**

Comment: check whether the element is inside a frame. if your element is inside an iframe tag (look complete hierarchy from the element to `html` tag and check whether `iframe` tag is present as a parent), then first you switch to the frame and then find the element inside of it. my detailed answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40759300/2575259

Comment: your help so awesome, work Perfectly!
i need to switch to iframe before click() **browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_name("iFrameName"))**

Comment: Thanks you very much, Naveen