# python .click() not working

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, xpath

I am currently using the following Python and Selenium versions:

Python34
3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06)[MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]

Selenium
VERSION 2.53.2

I am hoping someone will know the answer to this. What i am trying to achieve is to take a Facebook page, scroll it as far as it goes, and then expand all the 'comments', 'replies' and 'See More' links that appear down the page.

So far I have only tried with the 'See More' links but I cannot get it to process clicking on the link. I think my basic knowledge tells me that it finds the xpath as i don't get an error for this but I do for the .click function which is called immediately after. I have also tried using `find_element_by_link_text('See More')` however this didn't work. I also managed to locate the html structures where two examples of the See More links where located however as they weren't identical i wasn't sure how to implement these:

```
//div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span/a/span
//div[2]/div[2]/div/span/span/a/span

//div[@id='id_58591b7145b529535706885']/span/span/a/span
//div[@id='id_58591f8225af12f45796030']/span/span/a/span
```

If anyone has any suggestions or amendments or alternative options then i would be grateful to here them. Thanks in advance,

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Global Variables
target = "serena.xxxx.x"
username = "xxxxx@xxxxxx.com"
password = "xxxxxxxx"

#code block to log in user
def logmein():
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    search_box.send_keys(username)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('pass')
    search_box.send_keys(password)
    search_box.submit()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com//")

logmein()

elm = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
elm.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(2)
elm.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(2)
elm.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(2)
elm.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(2)
elm.send_keys(Keys.HOME)

# Initiates See More Open
SeeMore = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='see_more_link']")
print("Found See More")
SeeMore.click()
print("Expand SeeMore option")
```

Comment: _"What i am trying to achieve is to take a Facebook page, scroll it as far as it goes, and then expand all the 'comments', 'replies' and 'See More' links that appear down the page."_ - what for, what's the purpose of this? If you want to interact with content on Facebook, you should use their API. Using any such automated tools is explicitly forbidden by their ToS.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Global Variables
target = "..."
username = "..."
password = "..."

def logmein():
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    search_box.send_keys(username)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('pass')
    search_box.send_keys(password)
    search_box.submit()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com//")

logmein()

SeeMore = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'See More...')))
print("Found See More")
time.sleep(2) # apparently there is some javascript execution that requires this sleep to be here.
SeeMore.click()
print("Expand SeeMore option")
```

Would be great to see a screenshot of the mentioned link. This way I could go to an analog Facebook page and make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

"Display settings" -> "Scale and layout":

Size should be 100% - and that must match the ZOOM of your browser - also 100%

I have had this problem on IE for about 12 hours, tried all possible variations of clicking, hovering over element - then clicking, using `find_element_by_link_text`, updating everything .etc. and also tried some of the things that people suggested in stackoverflow - nothing worked.

Zooming to 100% in browser and setting display scale to 100% did the trick.