# Not able to click element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to click on service by using xpath

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/header/section/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/section/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
```

but element is not getting selected/clicked.please help

Comment: don't you have an easier way to get that element? based on one id from an element which is a parent? You don't receive `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: @john, can you provide the proper page source, So it would be easy to find which element is not clickable.

Comment: Add `HTML` sample for mentioned element. Also add exception log if you got any

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu1']"))`

try to use this. else

```
driver.findElement(By.id("menu1"))
```

Comment: what issue coming

Comment: how do you know id menu1 is available? i dont see any html code

Answer (score 0):

try as follows (if the element is not inside a frame):

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='menu1']/span[text()='Service']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='menu1']/span[text()='Service']")).click();
```

---

If above code does not work. then it is most probably the element is inside a frame.

If the element is inside a frame (the element is a child of an `iframe` tag), then first switch to the element and find the element.

My detailed answer about switching b/w frames here, 
[in selenium web driver how to choose the correct iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758138/in-selenium-web-driver-how-to-choose-the-correct-iframe)

Comment: Never prefer to use absolute XPath (starting from `html` element) which has higher percentage of failures. Always prefer relative XPaths (use element attributes, id etc. if not available use nearest parent who is having id/ attributes etc and then find the child).