# get value by Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to retrieve a value out of my html by Xpath.
For what it's worth, this is a CRM web tool(Microsoft's), and it looks like a dinamic iFrame which changes according to the link selected on its bar(Customers,Appeals etc...)

```html
<tbody><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{665A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{665A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" tabindex="0" title="A1" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{665A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}_0" target="_self" title="A1" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">A1</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding">02/08/2016 12:50</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{675A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{675A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" tabindex="0" title="A1.2" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{675A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}_1" target="_self" title="A1.2" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">A2</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding">02/08/2016 12:50</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{6B5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{6B5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" tabindex="0" title="A5" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{6B5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}_2" target="_self" title="A5" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">A5</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding">02/08/2016 12:50</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{6C5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{6C5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" tabindex="0" title="A6" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{6C5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}_3" target="_self" title="A6" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">A6</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding">02/08/2016 12:50</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{6D5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{6D5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}" tabindex="0" title="A9" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{6D5A4B9C-9658-E611-922C-441EA1745BC2}_4" target="_self" title="A9" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">A9</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding">02/08/2016 12:50</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr></tbody>
```

I'm using :

```
var nobrValues = _webdriverIE.FindElements(By.XPath("//nobr[@class='gridcellpadding']"));
```

but the result is 0. meaning no objects found. 
I also tried:

```
var _tableOfInterestsCount = _webdriverIE.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='gridBodyTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td"));
        var nobrvalues = var nobrValues = _tableOfInterestsCount.FindElements(By.XPath("//nobr[@class='gridcellpadding']"));
```

but again, no nobr's found(Count is 0).
basically, I would like to get one(or all of them) of the following values out of my html : A1,A1.2,A5,A6,A9.

the table in HTML

```html
<table class="ms-crm-List-Data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" rules="rows" morerecords="0" totalrecordcount="3" allrecordscounted="1" oname="10046" numrecords="3" tabindex="0" primaryfieldname="new_name" summary="foo" border="1" id="gridBodyTable" style="border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <colgroup><col width="18px" class="ms-crm-List-CheckBoxColumn"><col width="302" name="new_name" class="ms-crm-List-DataColumn ms-crm-List-SortedColumn"><col width="127" name="createdon" class="ms-crm-List-DataColumn"><col></colgroup><thead><tr class="ms-crm-Hidden-List"><th scope="col" class="ms-crm-Hidden-List"></th><th scope="col" class="ms-crm-Hidden-List">שם</th><th scope="col" class="ms-crm-Hidden-List">created at</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{5843AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content" selected="false">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{5843AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" tabindex="0" title="1" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="name1"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{5843AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}_0" target="_self" title="name 1" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">A1</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="20/02/2017 08:55">20/02/2017 08:55</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{5943AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content" selected="false">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{5943AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" tabindex="0" title="3" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="A5"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{5943AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}_1" target="_self" title="3" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">3</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="20/02/2017 08:55">20/02/2017 08:55</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{5A43AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content" selected="false">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{5A43AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" tabindex="0" title="9" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="9"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{5A43AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}_2" target="_self" title="9" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">9</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding">20/02/2017 08:55</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr></tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following XPATH for the 1st element (`A1`):

```
 var nobrValues = _webdriverIE.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/nobr/a"));
```

**Or**

If you already know the text i.e., `A1` (static content)

```
var nobrValues = _webdriverIE.FindElement(By.XPath("//nobr/a[text()='A1']"));
```

---

For `A2`:

```
var nobrValues = _webdriverIE.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/nobr/a"));
```

**Or**

If you already know the text i.e., `A2` (static content)

```
var nobrValues = _webdriverIE.FindElement(By.XPath("//nobr/a[text()='A2']"));
```

Please share `table` HTML code, so that we can make XPATH more **specific**.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. 
none of your options succeed.I'm getting an exception for the options which are not static content.
I'm getting the feeling that I'm not on the correct page. on the other hand, I can recognize that there are 2 tr's(meaning two rows) , but can't get the values in it.
BTW, It's a CRM (Microsoft's web tool).

Comment: could you post the exception trace? Also, check whether the table is inside a frame. If yes, you can look my answer here for more details related to switching b/w frames http://stackoverflow.com/a/40759300/2575259

Answer (score 0):

Try these below xpath.

To Get the value of **A1**

**Explanation:** Here your element is inside the `table`. so, start xpath with `tr` tag, then move ahead with `td` tag and `nobr` tag. Use `class` attribute of `nobr` tag and move ahead with `a` tag with `text` method.

```
//tr/td/nobr[@class='gridcellpadding']/a[contains(text(), 'A1')]
```

To Get the value of **3**

```
//tr/td/nobr[@class='gridcellpadding']/a[contains(text(), '3')]
```

To Get the value of **9**

```
//tr/td/nobr[@class='gridcellpadding']/a[contains(text(), '9')]
```