# checkbox xpath clarification Selenium web driver using java - sales force application

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

HTML code

```
<div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer" data-aura-rendered-by="2805:0">
<div class="rssDialogText grantAccessCheckbox packagingSetupUIRssDialogFooter" data-aura-rendered-by="2595:0" data-aura-class="packagingSetupUIRssDialogFooter">
<input type="checkbox" id="2596:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2600:0" class="uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox" data-aura-class="uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox" data-interactive-lib-uid="157">
```

Action:

Click the Checkbox

my xpath

```
//input[@data-aura-class='uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox']
```

or

```
//input[@class='uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox']
```

but both xpath not working, i am getting no such element

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox']"}
```

**checkbox click code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-aura-class='uiInp‌​ut uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox']")).click();
```

Note: checkbox id dynamic

Please resolve or correct my xpath

[image]

Comment: How about `//div[@data-aura-class="packagingSetupUIRssDialogFooter"]/input[@type="checkbox"]`? Also share code you use to click on checkbox

Comment: how about `//div[contains(class,'uiInputCheckbox') and @type="checkbox"]` please change the class if you don't get unique element. Also are how are you verifying your xpath, hope you are using firebug for that.

Comment: @andersson: chcekbox click code driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox']")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-aura-class='uiInput uiInputCheckbox uiInput--default uiInput--checkbox']")).click();

Comment: your XPath seems to be correct (though can be optimized), please check whether the checkbox element is inside an `iframe`. Refer my complete answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40759300/2575259 about switching b/w frames

Comment: @andersson: you xpath - SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@data-aura-class="packagingSetupUIRssDialogFooter"]/in‌​put[@type="checkbox"‌​]' is not a valid XPath

Comment: @naveen: not iframe this is located inside the model popup

Comment: @Prabu, this might be because of some hidden characters- they might appears when you make copy/paste from StackOverflow. To check it- paste code in `cmd`/`Terminal`- hidden chars should appears as `??`

Answer (score 0):

This might be timing issue: in case `input` field generated dynamically -it might be initially not present in `DOM`. Try below code to wait until checkbox present in `DOM` and it's clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@data-aura-class='packagingSetupUIRssDialogFooter']/in‌put[@type='checkbox']"))).click();
```

Comment: Did you get `TimeOutException`?

Comment: yes i'm getting timeoutexception, image added in my question please refer

Comment: Are you sure it's not located inside an `iframe`? could you double-check elements' ancestors?

Comment: sure not in iframe, its model box

Comment: Ok. Try this `XPath` `//div[normalize-space(.)='Yes, grant access to these third-party web-sites']/input`. Same exception?