# Selenium - XPath - Searching for an element by the innerHTML

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm learning Selenium and have a decent grasp of XPath.

An issue I'm running into is that on a web page, there's an element I want to select that has a dynamically generated `id` and `class`. I had tried the following:

```
code = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@text='someUniqueString')]")
```

However, the element doesn't have any text. Instead it's a `<code>` element with JSON.

```
<codestyle="display: none" id="something-crazy-dynamic">
    {"dataIWantToGrab":{"someUniqueString":...}}
</code>
```

I'm looking to search the `innerHTML` to find a unique string using CPU, but I can't find any good resources.

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@innerHTML='someUniqueString')]")
```

but I am receiving the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(@innerHTML='someUniqueString')]
```

Below is a link to the sibling text I'm working with

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b227e59c942e7ec9f5a851a3b7ecdfc6

---

I was able to get around this, not by using Selenium, but with [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)). It is not ideal, but it is still a solution.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
codes = soup.find_all("code")
found_json = [i for i in codes if i.text.find("someUniqueString") > 0]
```

Comment: Is any part of the `id` is constant or is it all dynamic?

Comment: there is a part that is constant but about 15 other elements have the same naming conventions

Comment: you can depend on parent, child, and siblings. please share the relevant HTML code (5 elements above and below the given element)

Comment: @Naveen - I've included more html here - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b227e59c942e7ec9f5a851a3b7ecdfc6

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't use XPath to match by inner HTML, but you can use it to match by 'inner text':

```
//*[text()[contains(., 'someUniqueString')]]
```

**<kbd>[`demo](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/JDHq197A1)</kbd>**

The above XPath expression should return the `code` element since it is the parent element of the target text 'someUniqueString'.

Comment: the issue I'm facing is that `innerTEXT` is returning null, but `innerHTML` is not

Comment: @kmomo It isn't literally `innerTEXT` that I meant, see the code snippet above. Looks like `innerHTML` is Selenium thing, so you might be able to use it. Only your XPath expression is a bit off, `=` should be replaced with `,` : `contains(@innerHTML,'someUniqueString')`

Comment: that's not working - `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@innerHTML,'someUniqueString')]")` is returning `Message: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(@innerHTML,'someUniqueString')]`

Comment: @kmomo did you try the XPath in this answer too? `//*[text()[contains(., 'someUniqueString')]]`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(text(),'someUniqueString')]
```

Note: As the `code` element is set with `display: none`, the element is *not* visible, though you **can find** the element. If you try to interact with the element using `click` or other API, you might get `ElementNotVisisbleException`. To put it simply, you can't interact with the elements which are *not* displayed in the GUI (browser).

---

If you are *not* able to find the element, then there are good chances that your element is inside an `iframe`. In such cases, you must switch to the frame first and then use the XPath to find the element.

More details on switching between frames are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759300/2575259).